# What is this part of laptop is this?

Tags: laptop

So I'm picking apart a HP laptop but trying to figure out what part this is?

[image: Picture of laptop interior]

Answer (score 0):

The labeled items are correct. The wireless card is apparent by the black wire and connector which probably has a matching one, both for the wireless antenna that routes to the display/cover. The RAM is indeed the memory and the one in the middle is probably an SSD, Solid State Drive. If your computer displays two "hard" drives, it's the "what is this" drive for booting and OS and the spinning media hard drive for user files and the like.

There will be a label under the black plastic providing specifications for the drive. You may also find a metal slab on the cover that corresponds to the placement of the black material, which provides heat sink/thermal transfer from the SSD.